# Plist for persistent data in UITableView between launches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, plist

I have this plist, called `sleeps.plist` in my main directory. It looks like 
[image]

I want to put it's contents into a UITableView... So I subclassed a `ViewController` with a `TableView` and I set it as the data source and delegate.

I've made it so that anything in the `NSArray` 'sleeps' gets added to the Table (tested out with static data).

Now, I want to be able to add data from this plist so the data (if a user enters more) stays persistent between launches.

Here's the code I put in my `viewDidLoad` of my `ViewController` subclass.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sleeps" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *myDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSArray *myArray = [myDict objectForKey:@"Root"];
sleeps = [myArray copy]; //sleeps is an NSArray declared right after the @implementation line

NSLog(@"reached point");

NSLog(@"%@", sleeps);
```

It logs reached point, and then null... So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Also, the table is empty. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your plist root is an array and not a dictionary, your code should be:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sleeps" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

sleeps = [myArray copy]; //sleeps is an NSArray declared right after the @implementation line

NSLog(@"reached point");

NSLog(@"%@", sleeps);
```

If you want the user to be able to add values then `sleeps` should be an `NSMutableArray` and you should call `[myArray mutableCopy]`.

But if you want to persist the additional data then you need to write the array to a writable folder such as the Documents folder.

Comment: How would I write to the documents folder? Would I write my plist to it or would I just write like an array or a dict?

Comment: Just use `[sleeps writeToFile:someProperPath atomically:YES]` where `someProperPath` is where you wish to write the file.

Comment: How do I find this path?

Comment: Please do some searching. There are countless existing questions here or via Google on how to write a file to the Documents folder.

Answer (score 1):

"Root" as a key doesn't really exist, you have a plist containing an array of dictionaries, all you need is:

```
sleeps = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```